# PHP - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Sou novo na area de programação web e estou desenvolvendo um site em php, o php em si até que entendo bem como funciona mas quanto ao javascript nao tenho muita certeza sobre quando usar.

por exemplo, e uma tela do site há uma tabela com aproximadamente 100 itens que são enviados pelo PHP, eu havia feito uma paginação para visualizar melhor os dados na pagina, porem fiz isso pelo próprio PHP e por motivos de negocio foi tomada a decisão de carregar sempre os 100 registros em vez de carrega-los por pagina como eu havia feito no php.

Nesse caso achei interessante usar o javascript para manipular o html e fazer uma tabela paginada dinâmica, porem vale ressaltar que ao clicar nesses dados o javascript tambem preenche inputs que podem realizar um update via PHP no BD.

É correto esse tipo de abordagem ? PHP -> Javascript -> PHP ... Em que momento sei que devo usar javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Principal diferença**

**PHP:** Linguagem que roda no servidor.

**JS:** Linguagem que roda no cliente.

No seu exemplo, se tivessem 1 milhão de registros, você faria o download de todo esse conteúdo para a máquina do cliente e só depois faria o tratamento.

Nestes casos, por motivos de performance, devemos tratar as informações no servidor, para não "atolar" o cliente.

> **Quando usar:**

Isso varia bastante.

Cada caso é realmente um caso. O JS pode tornar a sua aplicação mais dinâmica.

Por exemplo, com uso de ajax, podemos trocar informações na tela (ou até a tela inteira) sem fazer um reload na página.

Por outro lado, você não vai conseguir fazer um script JS no cliente fazer uma consulta SQL no banco no servidor.

> **Paginação:**

Como última dica, aconselho que pagine suas informações no servidor, ou até mesmo, no banco de dados, para melhorar a performance da sua página.

E se atente. O JS nasceu no client mas hoje, com o nodejs, você pode utilizá-lo no servidor também. Desta forma, fique sempre atento ao contexto que está desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 0):

Sua implementação anterior usando PHP estava mais correta pois você não precisa enviar 100 itens de uma tabela sendo que será exibidos somente 10 por exemplo, acaba afetando desnecessariamente no desempenho. Então estava correto enviar somente o que vai se exibir, frameworks e componentes de tabelas usam este modo de implementar.

> É correto esse tipo de abordagem ? PHP -> Javascript -> PHP

Porque não seria? É exatamente isso que muitas ferramentas front-end fazem (React, Angular, etc...), elas utilizam JavaScript para fazer exatamente isso, realizar requisiões (via Ajax) para o back-end, no seu caso PHP, receber a resposta e exibir na tela.

> Em que momento sei que devo usar javascript ?

Você PODE usar em todo seu front, como já disse anteriormente, é justamente isso que muitos frameworks front-end fazem, porém você DEVE usar quando você precisa fazer uma interação com o usuário, ou algo dinâmico.